# Accessing line.end with TkInter text widget, relative to cursor location

Tags: python, text, tkinter

The following script opens a text file with the TkInter text widget. The `get_location` function lets users click on the text editor, and it will show the location of the cursor. This uses the index `CURRENT`, which corresponds to the character closest to the mouse pointer.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

filename = "textfile1.txt"

with open(filename, "rt", encoding='latin1') as in_file:
    readable_file = in_file.read()

def get_location(event):
    print(textPad.index(CURRENT))

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(1.0, readable_file)
text.bind('<Button-1>', get_location)
text.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
scroll=Scrollbar(text)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.config(command=text.yview)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
root.mainloop()
```

The output location is in the form `line.column`, i.e. the beginning location is `1.0`, and the location at `16.11` is line 16, eleventh index of the string.

How can I access `line.end`? When the user clicks on a paragraph and outputs a location (e.g. `16.11`), I would like to know the beginning of that paragraph (`16.0`) and the end of that paragraph (`16.len(number of characters in paragraph)`)

The goal is to save the string between the beginning and end of the paragraph, based on where the user clicks.

Comment: You might want to check this answer which covers [end position of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477106/how-do-i-get-the-line-and-column-of-the-end-position-of-text-in-tkinter) or effbot's [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) page

Comment: @Lafexlos I noticed that. However, I would like the `.index("end")` of the paragraph which I am clicking. If I click on paragraph ("line") 16 at location `16.75`, the end index should be the end index for `16`.

Comment: @Lafexlos I'm also not entirely sure how to access `16.0` using the index methods listed on effbot's page. Somehow you have to strip the first integer from `%d.%d`, and proceed to place it in `%d.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a an existing index (eg: `16.11`, CURRENT, "insert", etc), the first character of that line can be referenced with `"16.11 linestart"`, and the last character is `"16.11 lineend"`

If you want the start of the line that contains the `CURRENT` index, you can use the literal word `"current"`, as in `"current linestart"` and `current lineend`. If you prefer to use the constant, use string concatenation: `CURRENT + " lineend"`.

The definitive description of text widget indices can be found on the tcl/tk man page for the text widget: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M7

Comment: I am slightly unclear what you mean by "referenced". The existing index is decided upon using the CURRENT index, which is accessed with a cursor click via `bind()`. For `%d.%d`, the first index could be any integer. Could you give a concrete example? Thank you for the help! I appreciate it

Comment: `CURRENT` is just the literal string `"current"`. You can use `"current linestart"` and `"current lineend"` if you wish.

Comment: Perfect! I understand now. Thank you! BTW, what is behind the index function? That is, how is the "end of a line" defined? Does it do a regex search ?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: it doesn't use regular expressions. Internally, the data in the text widget is stored in a tree structure for efficiency.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the help!